# Logically How Can a Set Contain Itself?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-theory, paradoxes

I was thinking about the idea of a set containing itself and that's driving me crazy.

An example of such set is the set of all things that are not turtles, since our set is a "set" then it's not turtle which means it's contained inside itself... but How is this even possible?

let's say set A is included in itself, then outer A just got bigger with another element then inner A gets bigger, then outer A gets bigger and so on.
This never ends, it seems like a recursive...

Comment: That being said, there is nothing preventing an object in computer programming from containing a reference to itself, or containing something that contains a reference to itself etc...  It is not so much that it anything is getting "bigger" and "bigger" as a result, just that as you drill down you might see something you've already seen before.

Comment: In javascript for instance, in a browser console type:  `testobj = {};  testobj.inner = testobj;` and explore the object that resulted.  Just don't try to expand it fully since you won't be able to.  Don't try to run `JSON.stringify(testobj)` as that will throw errors or try to loop through the children as that can start an infinite loop that will cause your computer to run out of memory.

Comment: You are not thinking in terms of sets. A set contains another set if it contains all elements from the other set. Clear enough, it does not have to be "bigger".

Comment: "the set of all things that are not turtles" . If with "things" you also mean sets , then you run into the same problem as if you ask for the set of all sets , which does not exist.